# Fastest way to find first uppercase character in a string

Tags: php, string, character, uppercase

Suppose you have this string:

`hiThere`

What is the fastest way to find where the first upper case character is? (`T` in this example)

I am worried about performance as some words are quite long.

Comment: You want first any uppercase letter or just first uppercase "T" ?

Comment: @HardikPatel: It's not "of course", it's not clear from the question.

Comment: i edited my question but just in case, is any uppercase, T was an example. thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Easiest would be to use preg_match (if there is only 1 match) or preg_match_all (if you want all the matches)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Not sure if it is the fastest..

Comment: `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` - that was the flag I was trying to thing of to get the match position.

Answer (score 7):

In order to find the first uppercase character, I would use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$string = "hiThere";

preg_match( '/[A-Z]/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

print_r( $matches[0] );
```

Which returns the following:

```
Array ( [0] => T [1] => 2 )
```

You could wrap this logic up into a function and use it over and over:

```
function firstUC ( $subject ) {
  $n = preg_match( '/[A-Z]/', $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
  return $n ? $matches[0] : false;
}

echo ( $res = firstUC( "upperCase" ) ) ? $res[1] : "Not found" ;
// Returns: 5

echo ( $res = firstUC( "nouppers!" ) ) ? $res[1] : "Not found" ;
// Returns: Not found
```

Answer (score 6):

Other way of doing

```
$stringCamelCase = 'stringCamelCase';// hiThere
```

Way with preg_split():

```
$array      = preg_split('#([A-Z][^A-Z]*)#', $stringCamelCase, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo strlen($array[0]);// $array = ['string', 'Camel', 'Case']
```

Way with strpbrk():

```
$CamelCase = strpbrk($stringCamelCase, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
echo strpos($stringCamelCase, $CamelCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine doing this:

```
strlen(preg_replace("/^([a-z]*)[A-Z].*$/", "$1", $str));
```

`isThis` => `2`
`largerWord` => `6`

Comment: Awesome but I don't quite understand why this works. although i get 12 on this string `$str = 'asas.2tAOPPr';` :/

Comment: K i figured it out. It attempts to retrieve the first set of characters that are all lowercase. It does not account for numbers but most camel cased strings won't have numbers in the middle of it. then gets the length of those characters. if it can't find a match it returns the length of the entire string.

Comment: Pretty much. Guess you could run "/^([^A-Z])*[A-Z].*$/" otherwise.

Comment: I just added the numbers into the first bracket to get a similar working as your original answer -------------------
 `/ ^([a-z\d]*)[A-Z].*$` as I didnt really want the full stops in there

Answer (score 1):

Use `strpos()`.

```
echo strpos($string, "T");
```

Comment: He wants general code not specific to that code. Say your code would fail when he wants "X" from string "abcXyz"

Comment: @UmakantPatil: The question has been edited since I wrote this answer.  (3 times). Its meaning was altered greatly since. I would appreciate if you could review the revisions next time when downvoting a very old answer (This answer is more than a year old).

Comment: Sorry about that. I would have revoked vote down but I'm not able to do it as it says "Your vote is locked down"

Comment: @UmakantPatil: It's alright, I'll delete this answer when I get home since it really no longer applies. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (more or less) one line solution.

```
$pos = strcspn($string, 'ABCDEFGHJIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

[strcspn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php) will return the position of the first occurrence of any character in the second argument, or the length of the string if no character occurs.

> Returns the length of the initial segment of str1 which does not contain any of the characters in str2.

```
$pos = strcspn($string, 'ABCDEFGHJIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
if ($pos < strlen($string)) {
    echo "capital letter as index $pos";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the darndest time with this function till I found the array is a multi-dimensional. Didn't see anyone's code mention this. To get the position of the first Capitalized letter I used :

```
<?php

$field = "i_select_Interior_Quote";
preg_match( '/[A-Z]/', $field, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

$posi=$m[0][1];

echo '<br><br>'.$posi; // outputs 9

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for a-z characters. Probably wont work unicode

```
 preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $str, $m);
 if(isset($m[1])) {
    echo 'First upper char is '.$m[1].' and located at '. strpos($string, "T");
 }
 else {
    'There is no upperchar';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**What I have used in my own application:**

```
function acronyms($s){
  $s=str_replace(array('& ','of ','the ','and '),'',strtolower($s));
  $s=ucwords(trim($s)); //Collecting data
  if(strlen($s)>0 && preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/',$s,$m))   return implode('',$m[0]);
return $s;
}
```